# Is there any way to recover or reinstall ChromeOS after accidentally running “rm -rf /”

Tags: linux, chromebook, google-chrome-os

I use developer mode on my Chromebook. At the time, I was so sleep deprived, I somehow managed to `rm -rf /` in the console.

I have probably lost a lot on there, it was pretty old.

Is there any way to recover or reinstall ChromeOS?

I mostly need to reinstall it.

Comment: Probably not. No backups? Sorry.

Comment: Chromebooks have a recovery mode. Tried that yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ChromiumOS rootfs is mounted read-only. Unless you explicitly made it writeable and mounted it, it should still be intact.

As for the userdata, its hard to say given limited knowledge about the circumstances, or any such experience previously running that command. (why?)

The options I can suggest (difficulty and payoff in decreasing order):

- As your device is already in developer mode I will assume you are the owner and if so, there is a chance you could extract the whole user partion following [Chromebooks forensic aquisition techniques published by Daniel Dickerman et. al.](https://dfir.pubpub.org/pub/inkjsqrh/release/)
- Recovery your Chromebook and select the a [local/stateful recovery](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/13839736?hl=en-GB&sjid=1038052929606038270-EU) option, if successful, might also recover your files that may have been unsuccessfully deleted after the command was run.
- Recovery your chromebook by using the [Chromebook Recovery Utility](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/chromebook-recovery-utili/pocpnlppkickgojjlmhdmidojbmbodfm) to create recovery media and clean install the OS.